# limit enum values for a select box

Tags: grails

In some parts of my app the webpage needs to have a select box for 2 options - Male, Female.  In other parts of the app the select box needs to have 3 options - Male, Female, or Unknown

In the g:select, how can I pass in a subset of the enum for the from field, while not changing the way the keys or value parameters are written?  The g:select is in a taglib and accepts any type of Enum (even though it shows Gender, this is actually a passed-in field to the taglib), so the only field
that can be changed is the from field in the calling gsp.

gsp:

```
 <myapp:select fieldName="gender" 
                                  from="${Gender}"
                                  value="${command?.gender?.key}" noSelection="${['':'No answer...']}" />
```

taglib:

```
            <g:select name="${fieldName}"
                      from="${from.values()}"
                      keys="${from.values()*.name()}"
                      value="${value}"
                      noSelection="${noSelection}"/>
```

Enum class:

```
public enum Gender {
    M('Male'),
    F('Female'),
    U('Unknown')

    final String value

    Gender(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }
    public String toString() {
        value
    }
    public String getKey() {
        name()
    }
    public String getValue() {
        value
    }
}
```

Or is there a way to have a subclass of Gender that has the additional U('Unknown') option.  I've also tried this with no luck:

```
public static final List<Gender> getPartial() {
    [M, F]
}
```

Comment: Is this Enum getting persisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter it on your GSP or completely move it to your controller.

```
<g:select name="genderPreference" from="${GenderPreference.values().findAll {
       !it.value.contains('Male')
}}" 
keys="" value="${profileInstance?.genderPreference?.name()}" noSelection="['': '']"/>
```

You need to do the same thing for your `Keys`. It would be better to move it into your controller perhaps.

Comment: I ended up with a static method in the enum class using Alidad's approach:

 static def sexMFOnly() {
        Gender.values().findAll {!it.value.contains(Gender.U.value) }.collect()
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could also - as you did - make it a little bit shorter:

```
static sexMFOnly(){ values() - U }
```